Asymptotic lines of a surface
Let $S$ the regular surface parametrized by the map
$$\varphi:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3, \quad \varphi(x,y)=(x,y,e^{x-y})$$
Find all the asymptotic lines of $S$.
Def. Let $\gamma:I\subseteq \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^3$ a $C^\infty$ regular curve such that $Im(\gamma)\subseteq S$.
We say that $\gamma$ is an asymptotic lines of $S$ iff $II_{\gamma(t)}(\gamma'(t))=0, \forall t\in I$; where $II_{\gamma(t)}$ is the second fundamental form of $S$ in $\gamma(t)$.
My attempt is the following.
Let $\gamma:I\subseteq\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^3$ a $C^\infty$ regular curve that lies on $S$.
The derivative $\gamma'(t)$ is a vector of the tangent plane $T_{\gamma(t)}S$ so I can write the following linear combination:
$$\gamma'(t)=a\cdot \varphi_x(x,y)+b\cdot \varphi_y(x,y)$$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$, not both zero, and $\varphi_x(x,y)=(1,0,e^{x-y})$, $\varphi_y(x,y)=(0,1,-e^{x-y})$ are the first derivatives  of $\varphi.$
Therefore, the coordinates of $\gamma'(t)$ with respect to the basis $\{\varphi_x(x,y),\varphi_y(x,y)\}$ of $T_{\gamma(t)}S$ are $(a,b)$.
Then, I impose the condition given by the definition:
$$II_{\gamma(t)}(\gamma'(t))=0 \Longleftrightarrow (a,b)\cdot II_{\gamma(t)}\cdot  (a,b)^t=0$$
where $II_{\gamma(t)}$ is the matrix associated to the second fundamental form of $S$ in $\gamma(t)$ and from the calculations I did before, it turns out to be the following:
$$II_{\gamma(t)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2e^{2(x-y)}+1}}\begin{pmatrix}e^{x-y} & -e^{x-y} \\ -e^{x-y} & e^{x-y}\end{pmatrix}$$
So, I have that:
$$(a,b)\cdot II_{\gamma(t)}\cdot  (a,b)^t=0 \Longleftrightarrow (a,b) \cdot \begin{pmatrix}e^{x-y} & -e^{x-y} \\ -e^{x-y} & e^{x-y}\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}a \\ b\end{pmatrix}=0  \Longleftrightarrow  (a-b)^2e^{x-y}=0$$
So, the equation is satisfied if $a=b$.
Therefore, I found that $\gamma'(t)=a(\varphi_x(x,y)+ \varphi_y(x,y))$ with $a\in \mathbb{R}$.
My professor corrected me the following facts: the second fundamental form is not calculated in $\gamma(t)$ and in the end I did not precisely determine the required curves.
Someone to help me?

Before you go any further, what is the Gaussian curvature $K$? So how many asymptotic curves are there through every point? Next: What are the curves in the parameter space (here the $xy$-plane) with $a=b$? Forget about $t$ and write an equation with $x$ and $y$.

I found that $K=0$ in every point and that every point is a parabolic point. So, there is only one asymptotic line that pass through a point. How can I describe this line in terms of $x,y$ coordinates?

Correct. Now draw the curves in the parameter space.

Ok, but how can I write an equation? I found that the tangent vector is $(1,1)$ and so the lines are $y=\pm x$ with respect to the coordinate given by $\varphi_x, \varphi_y$?

There are lots more lines. And no, not $\pm$. Don’t think about $\varphi_x$ and $\varphi_y$. If you know the curves in the parameter space, then you know the curves on the surface.

So, the curves are $\varphi(x,x)$ and $\varphi(x,-x)$ with $x\in \mathbb{R}$?

No. Did you read all my last comment? Where did $y=-x$ come from? And there is an asymptotic curve through every point, right?

Ok, but I cannot understand what I have to do...I have the eigenvector $(1,1)$ of the Weingarten matrix, that comes from $a=b$

In the plane, what are all the integral curves of the ODE $y'=1$?

Thanks. Hope you guide OP further on towards the fault in his question. Regards.

I found that the asymptotic lines are $\gamma(t)=(t+x_0,t+y_0,z_0)$ with $x_0,y_0,z_0\in \mathbb{R}$. Is it right?

Still not quite right. Doesn't $z_0=e^{x_0-y_0}$, which varies?

Of course, $z_0=e^{x_0-y_0}$ when $x_0,y_0$ are fixed otherwise the line does not belong to the surface. Thank you very much!

HINTS:
At any point $(u,v)$ direction of asymptotic line is $(du,dv)$ ..(which is also its self conjugate line).
Otherwise also directly from the second fundamental form with standard notation for vanishing normal curvature
$$L du^2+2M dudv +Ndv^2=0 \tag 1$$
For Mongé form surface  $z=f(x,y)$ we have the required ode
$$ r dx^2+ 2s dx dy +t dy^2=0 \tag 2 $$
where the coefficients are double derivative in x, mixed in x,y  and double in y directions respectively.
$$z= e^{x-y}; ~ (r,s,t)= e^{x-y}(1,-1,1) ~ ; ~dx^2- 2 dx dy + dy^2=0 \tag3 $$
In x-y plane ode is
$$y^{'2}-2 y'+1=0 \to y'= (1,1) \tag 4$$
etc.
EDIT1:
Proceeded to answer procedurally, assuming the given problem has an answer.
Negative Gauss curvature surfaces have two unique real asymptotes and direction of the two lines can be defined.
Only later noted that determinant of (2) vanishes as also the Gauss curvature $K=\dfrac{rt-s^2}{(1+p^2+q^2)^2}=0, $ valid for developable surfaces.
So can you at all find a pair of unique asymptotic lines?
